# Proper coded examples of MVC 3 error handling

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

I'm coming from the Winforms world where I trapped everything and handled errors with messages to the user with MessageBox.Show(ex.message) or just logged it.
Now I'm in the web (MVC 3) world and I can't seem to find a definitive coded example of how to employ proper error handling. Let me show you what I'm using:

User clicks on a link which runs a controller action:

```
Function SelectAlertKPIs() As ActionResult

    Try
        Return PartialView()

    Catch ex As Exception
        TempData("ErrorMessage") = "There was a problem during page load: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace
        Return RedirectToAction("HttpError", "Error")
    End Try

End Function
```

This view loads a Telerik grid with AJAX binding, so now the binding runs this action:

```
<GridAction()> _
Function _SelectAlertKPIs() As ActionResult

    Try
        Return PartialView(New GridModel(AlertKPIRepository.All()))

    Catch ex As Exception
        TempData("ErrorMessage") = "There was a problem during page load: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace
        Return RedirectToAction("HttpError", "Error")
    End Try

End Function
```

Which calls this method to get data:

```
Public Shared Function All() As IList(Of AlertKPI)

    Dim l As IList(Of AlertKPI) = Nothing

    Try
        Using dc As New AdminAlertKPIDataContext(TripleDESSecurity.Decrypt(SharedData.PortalCnx))
            l = (From d In dc.AdminAlertKPIs Order By d.ID Select New AlertKPI With {
                .ID = d.ID,
                .KPI = d.KPI,
                .KPIName = d.KPIName,
                .KPIDescription = d.KPIDescription
            }).ToList
        End Using

        Return l

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally
        If Not l Is Nothing Then l = Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```

These are my ErrorController actions:

```
Public Function HttpError() As ActionResult

    Dim s As String = String.Empty

    s = TempData("ErrorMessage")
    ViewData("ErrorMessage") = "An error occurred. " & s

    Return PartialView("Error")

End Function

Public Function Http404() As ActionResult

    Try
        ViewData("ErrorMessage") = "The page you requested could not be found"

        Return View("Error")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return View("Error")
    End Try

End Function
```

This is what I have in my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error/HttpError">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/Http404" />
</customErrors>
```

Now if I add code into my controller action to purposely throw:

```
Throw New HttpUnhandledException
```

Then it falls to the catch block, and then routes to the HttpError action.. Twice! and then my Error.aspx view never opens, instead I get either no JSON result or a 500 internal server error... makes not a lick of sense to me. Basically, I don't know what I'm doing.

And I could use some really good guidance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into `[HandleErrorAttribute]` - there is no need to polute your action methods with try catch blocks. You might want to implement your own error handler attribute for additional logging - which is what I'm doing today. This is today's post on exception handling: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658527/exception-vs-ad-hoc-type-what-is-likely-to-fall-over)

Your web config is for exceptions that occur outside of MVC application pipeline. IIS will be able to read the web config and then re-direct user to the correct page. Others, please correct me if I'm wrong as I only started looking at this today.

Comment: Can you provide actual coded samples? There is a lot of 'look into this or that' out there but within each of those there's too much noise as to what is the correct way. I'm looking for real examples to plug into the code I provided. I also don't understand why you say to move away from try/catch. This isn't pollution, it's pure safety from what I've been taught. Not using Try/Catch has always been a BAD thing in my world. So I can't wrap my ahead around why I should move away from that paradigm.